# Render table in partial Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, partial

Could someone help me render a table view partial? Basically, I have a Link model with two attributes: Description and URL. My Link model is a nested resource of my Opportunity model. Therefore when I click "show" on an opportunity, I want it to show the Opportunity then show all the links that belong to that opportunity. I want the links to be rendered into a table with columns labeled "Description" and "URL". My current code looks like this:

views/opportunities:

```
<%= render @opportunity %>
<h3>Links</h3>
<div id = "links">
  <%= render @opportunity.links %>
</div>
```

views/links/_link

```
<%= div_for link do %>

    <p>Description:<%= link.description %></p>
    <p>URL: <%= link.link_url %></p>
    <span class='actions'>
            <%= link_to 'Delete', [@opportunity, link], :confirm => 'Are you sure?',
                :method => :delete %>
    </span>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to want...

```
<%= render @opportunity %>
<h3>Links</h3>
<table id = "links">
  <thead><tr>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>URL</th>
  </tr></thead>

  <tbody>
    <%= render @opportunity.links %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And then...

```
<tr>
  <td><%= link.description %></td>
  <td><%= link.link_url %></td>
  <td><span class='actions'>
        <%= link_to 'Delete', [@opportunity, link], :confirm => 'Are you sure?',
            :method => :delete %>
  </span></td>
</tr>
```

I'm a little unclear on how you're using the span in the partial, so I left it as a separate column in the table.

I hope that helps.